# angular 2, karma,jasmine 404 not found issue

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-runner

I am trying to write a unit test for a component in angular2. The stack is angular2,karma,jasmine with Visual Studio as IDE. Find below the exception that occurred while running the unit tests through Gulp.

```
**16 03 2017 18:04:28.169:DEBUG [middleware:source-files]: Fetching E:/TestProject/app/component/SampleComponent

16 03 2017 18:04:28.170:WARN [web-server]: 404: /base/app/component/SampleComponent

Chrome 56.0.2924 (Windows 7 0.0.0) ERROR
  {
    "originalStack": "Error: Error: XHR error (404 Not Found) loading app/component/SampleComponent\n\tError loading app/component/SampleComponent as \"./SampleComponent\" from app/component/SampleComponent.spec.js",

    "zoneAwareStack": "Error: Error: XHR error (404 Not Found) loading app/component/SampleComponent\n\tError loading app/component/SampleComponent as \"./SampleComponent\" from app/component/SampleComponent.spec.js",

    "originalErr": {
      "originalStack": "Error: XHR error (404 Not Found) loading app/component/SampleComponent",
      "zoneAwareStack": "Error: XHR error (404 Not Found) loading app/component/SampleComponent"
    }
  }

Chrome 56.0.2924 (Windows 7 0.0.0) ERROR
  {
    "originalStack": "Error: Error: XHR error (404 Not Found) loading app/component/SampleComponent\n\tError loading app/component/SampleComponent as \"./SampleComponent\" from app/component/SampleComponent.spec.js",

    "zoneAwareStack": "Error: Error: XHR error (404 Not Found) loading app/component/SampleComponent\n\tError loading app/component/SampleComponent as \"./SampleComponent\" from app/component/SampleComponent.spec.js",

    "originalErr": {
      "originalStack": "Error: XHR error (404 Not Found) loading app/component/SampleComponent",
      "zoneAwareStack": "Error: XHR error (404 Not Found) loading app/component/SampleComponent"
    }
  }
16 03 2017 18:04:28.258:DEBUG [karma]: Run complete, exiting.
16 03 2017 18:04:28.259:DEBUG [launcher]: Disconnecting all browsers**
```

My folder structure is app\component

The tests are available within component folder itself. The related code in the transpiled js is as follows

```
const Component_1 = require("./SampleComponent");
const testing_1 = require("@angular/core/testing");
```

Request anyone to help on this.

Thanks

TTV

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it by the following statement in **karma.conf.js**

```
{ pattern: './app/component/LoginComponent.js', included: true, watched: false }
```

Please refer the below URL for complete information.

https://psamsotha.github.io/angular/2016/12/16/angular2-testing-karma-systemjs.html

Check it